# jQuery counter and adding a class but not to the first two?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm checking list items I have and if there are more than two then I add a class. This works fine but I want the class to start adding after the first two list items. I am not sure how to do that part that excludes adding the class to the first two. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Checking how many time the class appears
  var numItems = $('ul.singleMagazine li').length;
  if (numItems > 2) {
    alert(numItems);
    //Want to add this class but not to the first two - exclude first two list items and then add it to the rest. How to do it?
    $('ul.singleMagazine li').addClass("newClass");
  }
});
```

How I would do the excluding part?

Comment: you can use `gt()` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` elements should be siblings, so you can use the `gt()` selector:

```
$('ul.singleMagazine li:gt(1)').addClass("newClass");
```

Also note that the `length` check is redundant as if there's less than two items the above won't do anything anyway.

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for this. Is gt() new in jquery? I've never come across it in years.... Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, and not really - it was added in 1.0: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: Thanks again, shame I've not come across it beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gt` selector. https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

```
$('ul.singleMagazine li:gt(1)').addClass("newClass");
```

This will add the class only to the li's which are greater than 1. Note here that the indexing starts from 0.